# Swift UI StateObject Published two side communication

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, delegates, observedobject

I am new to this SwiftUI and would like to ask some questions.

There are three objects in total.
View1, View2, Object1.
Here's part of my code.

```
struct View1: View {
    @StateObject var object = Object1()
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            View2(object: object)

            Button(action: {} )
        }
    }

    func isOverchanged() { //doSomething }
}

struct View2: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var object = Object1()
}

class Object1: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var mydata: [Double] = []
    @State var isOver: Bool = false
}
```

I want to achieve two goals.

The first one is that "view2" to be notified if there is a change in myData inside "object".

The second one is that isOverChanged function in "view1" to be notified (Or notify the button action closure) if the isOver inside the object changes.

The first goal has been achieved.
But the second one tried a lot without success.

If it is the way of writing ViewController delegate, I can set delegate.onIsOverChanged(). But when it comes to SwiftUI I don't know what to do.

Here is part of the delegate version that may looks like.

```
protocol ObjectProtocol {
    onMyDataChanged()
    onIsOverChanged()
}

class View1: UIViewController, ObjectProtocol {
    var object: Object1 = Object(delegate: self)
    var view2: View2 = View2()

    func onMyDataChanged() {
        view2.doSomething()
    }

    func onIsOverChanged() {
        //doSomething
    }
}

class Object1: NSObject {
    weak var delegate: ObjectProtocl?
    var isOver = false
    func isOverChanged(){
        delegate?.onIsOverChanged()
    }

    func myDataChanged(){
        delegate?.onMyDataChanged()
    }
}

class View2: UIView {
    func doSomething(){ }
}
```

Really thanks.

Comment: `@State` only works inside of a `SwiftUI` `View` not a `class` and anything that Ising your top `ObservableObject` should be a `struct`. Also, every time you call `Object1()` you create a different instance, one does not know what the other is doing. try the SwiftUI Tutorials.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try to read the tutorial. Looks like something has changed.

Comment: No changes these are common errors.